# How to minimize all open apps using python

Tags: python

I am trying to achieve a functionality in which I can minimize other apps leaving only my current active window on my app using python. How can this be done?

A similar function is done using Windows + Home key, but how can I do this in my app?

Platform : WxPython
O.s      : Windows

Comment: Horrible idea from the UX perspective. Also I like to see two programs with the same idea interact with each other.

Comment: [What if two programs did this?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413). Read it before doing anything similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to pynput by using

```
pip install pynput
```

Now use this code to press Windows + Home key

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

keyboard.press(Key.cmd)
keyboard.press(Key.home)
keyboard.release(Key.home)
keyboard.release(Key.cmd)
```

Then add delay to switch the app you want. Otherwise, it will keep only the python shell. I am adding 5 seconds delay you can change it as you want.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from time import sleep

keyboard = Controller()

sleep(5)  # this is 5 seconds change as you want

keyboard.press(Key.cmd)
keyboard.press(Key.home)
keyboard.release(Key.home)
keyboard.release(Key.cmd)
```

Comment: @Oshadhi Can you tell me what `Key.cmd` would represent in a Linux/Macintosh machine?

Comment: What a great solution, thanks @Osadhi Virochana

Comment: @ParamSiddharth It corresponds to the Windows key on Windows and Command key on Mac and It is also called as Super key